# How to merge a git repository and some other local storage files?

Tags: git

We've pushed a repository. It was pushed to master 1 month ago and developers has worked on it, has created branches merged codes, etc..

On the other hand another developer has worked on the codes which are before the pushing to master. And this developer's code isn't on the git. So his code doesn't contain the changes on the repository. Let's call his codes as local X.

I want to merge them them together. But decide which code is useful and which is not. I've tried these on local X:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/xyz/xyz
git pull origin master
```

It doesn't pull. I couldn't decide what should I do.

Comment: You want to `git clone` and then `merge` the diverged remotes. Or are you saying the maverick developer never `git clone`d the original repo in tae first place?

Comment: Yes @tripleee that's exactly what I mean. Maverick developer has never git clone and has never work on repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *local X* diverged from the upstream code after commit `123abcd`, you can `git clone` into a new directory, create a new `branch-x` at that commit, then copy in the developer's changes into this branch and commit and push it. Merging that to `master` would then follow normal Git work flows.

```sh
git clone "$url" upstream
cd upstream
git checkout 123abcd
# detached branch
git checkout -b x-branch
# now copy in changes
cp ../local-x/changedfile ./
cp ../local-x/subdir/*.py ./subdir/
:
git add -A
git commit -m "Checked in changes from 1+ month of random activity"
git push origin branch-x
```

There is no need *per se* to actually push this new branch before merging it; but I think it will feel a lot safer to have a pushed, well-defined point in history to revert to if you need to undo some or all of your subsequent work to merge it to `master`.

If there are any newly added files, `git add` them separately before the final commit and push. Obviously, if you can structure this into more than one whopper commit, it's probably going to be more manageable for anyone who tries to understand the final merge to `master`.

Whether the local branch diverged before or after the very first commit isn't really a crucial question; you could in theory have a branch which isn't ultimately rooted at the very first commit, but I don't think it really adds any value here.

Comment: But maverick developer's some codes are old. Doesn't it change the other developers' code?

Comment: Checking in a change which reverts a change which happened before the first commit on `master` will look like a forward change in `branch-x`, yes; but the final merge should take care to revert any suoh changes. There's only so much you can expect `git` to be able to infer or guess without manual intervention or at least manual verification in this rather pathological situation.

Comment: By the way do you mean -A by -a  on the git add?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to ask your colleague to clone the repo, create a branch, override/add with his file, and push.

After that you'll be able to merge the 2 branches